# Calculate end point of a vector pointing from another vector while knowing magnitude and angle of both

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am going to calculate the end point for the green vector (its coordinates)

[Picture of vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7oCh.png)

I know the magnitudes of both as well as the angles between them. I also know that, in general, to find the x coordinate of a given vector, you just take magnitude * cos(angle) and magnitude * sin(angle) for the y coordinate.

The angle alpha is pi/3 and the angle beta is pi/4. The length of the red vector is 60cm while the green has a length of 40cm

However, how can I calculate the end point of the green vector while preserving the fact that the green vector is pointing away from the end point of the red vector?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by just simply setting the angle for the green vector as $\alpha$+$\beta$